problem with using GPIO to program buttons
I have a project I'm struggling with. I must create a device that starts and manipulates audio through buttons connected to jumper wires on an Orange Pi board, but programming them has been a big challenge for me as I have no experience in this.
So far I've created a circuit for the buttons with help from the internet, as well as making a gpio_keys and a DTS file called button-overlay.
But when I test the buttons using the evtest command in the terminal, nothing happens.
I will describe how my gpio_keys and button-overlay files look like.
GPIO:
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/{
   compatible = "allwinner, sun8i-h3";
   fragment {
       target = <&pio>;
       _overlay_ {
           gpio_keys_user: gpio_keys_user {
               compatible = "gpio-keys";
               pinctrl-names = "default";
               pinctrl-0 = <&pio_button_0>;

               play_pause {
                   label = "Play/Pause";
                   linux, code = <164>; /*KEY_PLAYPAUSE*/
                   gpios = <&pio 0 7 0>; /* PA7 */
               };
               next {
                   label = "Next";
                   linux, code = <163>; */KEY_NEXTSONG*/
                   gpios = < &pio 0 8 0>; /* PA8 */
               };

               previous {
                   label = "Previous";
                   linux, code = <165>; /*KEY_PREVIOUSSONG*/
                   gpios = <&pio 0 9 0>; /*, PA9 */
               };
           };
       };
    };
};

Button overlay:
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/{
    compatible = "brcm, bcm2835", "brcm, bcm 2708", "brcm, bcm 2709";
    fragment@0 {
        target = <&pio>;
        _overlay_ {
           button8: my_button8 {
               compatible = "gpio-keys";
               #adress-cells = <1>;
               #size-cells =<0>;
               pinctrl-names = "default";
               pinctrl-0 = <&button8_pin>;
               status = "okay";

               but-pla {
                   label = "button-gpio8"
                   linux, code = <8>;
                   gpios = <&gpio 8 0>;
               };
            );
         };
     };
};

I don't know if this information is enough, but I can send you anything else you want to note.

compatible strings should have no spaces after commas. E.g., "brcm,bcm2708" is correct, while yours are not. Also, add the output of lsmod and add the steps on how you load those overlays. Btw, should be linux,code and not with a space after the comma. I'm not sure if it will fix your issues, but these are very visible mistakes. And #size-cells = <0> should have a space after = but it most likely will have the same effect, so it's only for readability.

Next one is the wrong comment style (you should have /* and not */ one at the beginning. Then how are you sure that the PAx pins have the linear numbering of the referred pins as PA9 == 9?

@0andriy I consulted an Orange.Pi guide file (http://www.orangepi.org/html/hardWare/computerAndMicrocontrollers/service-and-support/Orange-Pi-PC.html), it indicates the position of the pins. I will make the changes you specified. I have a question about linux,code, should the event code generated by the button be placed here?

Link you mentioned refers to the several files. I'm not sure what exactly you are referring to. The linux,code is the key code that will be generated by the button. They are listed here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h#L65.

Here is article related to VLC side of the configuration: https://superuser.com/questions/237098/how-do-i-associate-my-keyboards-media-keys-with-vlc-media-player. (Here is for command line https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)

@0andriy I think what still stops me from proceeding is the button-overlay, I'm trying to understand how the file construction works so I can do it right

Honestly, I don't know what you are doing there. The both files are about GPIO keys (buttons), do you need them both? Why, if so? Also you haven't added any update to your Q, so it's unclear if you fixed the mistakes I pointed out. Btw, in the second file you use target phandle pio while button uses gpio. I don't know enough about DT overlays and the mentioned platforms, I'm not sure which is correct. Also compatible strings should match your hardware (platform / board).
